# Setting Windows Explorer to Details view by default (script or registry - winXP)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, windows-registry

We are often deploying a bunch of laptops for trainings and exams, and the need sometimes arises for the default windows explorer view to be "details" as opposed to the icon view. I have tried using procmon to check what registry keys change when I swap it to this Details view, with very limited success (there's a ton of keys that get read and changed at any one time).

Has anyone tried to do this recently? Googling the question turned up nothing so far, a bunch of results but they all seem to be outdated with keys nowhere to be found in the registry or simply not doing what is advertised.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go under Explorer's Tools Menu.  Folder Options then *Apply this view to all folders*.